# Forwarding message to Message Channel manually - Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration

Am able to send the message successfully using the below from my FirstHandler

messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(pa).build());

But, the flow is waiting for the handler2 associated with the messageChannel to complete.

I would like to just forward the data to the channel and forgot , I tried publish-subscribe & direct channel both wait for the handler2 to complete

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, learn what types of `MessageChannel` implementations are there: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations

That's correct that `DirectChannel` is just calling the `MessageHandler` in the same sending thread. The `PublishSubscribeChannel` has the same behavior by default.

If you'd like to send-n-forget, then you need a `MessageChannel` which shifts consuming task to a different thread. For this purpose there are `QueueChannel`, `ExecutorChannel` and `FluxMessageChannel`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, Implemented with the ExecutorChannel.